# Complete all threads even if one throws exception

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I want to execute a number of jobs in separate threads in Kotlin 1.5.30. If one job fails, I want the others to carry on regardless. In the following demo code, when the second job throws an exception, all the other jobs get cancelled, hence it prints "2" at the end:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger

fun main() = runBlocking(Dispatchers.Default) {
    val count = AtomicInteger(0)
    val deferred = List(10) {
        async {
            if (count.incrementAndGet() == 2)
                throw Exception("test")
        }
    }
    try {
        deferred.awaitAll()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        println("Exception caught")
    }
    println(count)
}
```

How can I get it to complete all jobs even if some fail, so that the final output is "10"?

Comment: I think a [SupervisorJob](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/exception-handling.html#supervision) is what you want, so exceptions don't propagate upwards. What do you think?

Comment: @aSemy thanks, I've looked it up and it seems to do what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider calling `async` in the context of `SupervisorJob`:

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.SupervisorJob
import kotlinx.coroutines.async
import kotlinx.coroutines.awaitAll
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger

fun main() = runBlocking {
    val supervisor = SupervisorJob()
    val count = AtomicInteger(0)
    val deferred = List(10) {
        async(supervisor) {
            if (count.incrementAndGet() == 2)
                throw Exception("test")
        }
    }
    try {
        deferred.awaitAll()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        println("Exception caught")
    }
    println(count)
}
```